# How do I keep track of the data represented by a view?

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller

I'm attempting to do a better job of keeping my data and my visual representation of data separate in a new project and I'm having some trouble with the abstraction.

I have a list of objects in a set that are part of an inventory and I use that data to generate some UIImageViews that get placed into the interface, thus keeping my models and views separate. When a user taps on the UIImageView, I want to be able to take an action on the data in the set as well as modifying the corresponding view.

How do I keep track of the object that is being represented by the UIImageView? I would think there's some sort of mechanism by which I can say "here's a reference to the object that you represent" but I can't figure out if that exists or if there's a more accepted way to achieve the view/model separation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create and object that is an extension of the ImageView and upon initialization of that view, associate a property in the view to your data associated with the view.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean - you're suggesting creating a subclass of UIImageView with a single additional property that is the object I want to keep reference to, right? Does this have any memory management considerations?

Comment: as long as you clean up the memory when you delloc your subclass you should be fine